# Xcode UI Testing plan

Tags: ios, user-interface, testing, architecture, ui-automation

I would like to implement UI Testing for my app, but I couldn't find anywhere some guides on how to structure the tests, group them or which is the best way to proceed writing the tests - a big flow in a test, or multiple tests for smaller flows.
If you have some resources regarding these topics, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as reference https://www.raywenderlich.com/960290-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial

and this one https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/148/xcode-ui-testing-cheat-sheet

For UI Testing, you must record first your test cases, and Xcode will fill automatically the codes for you(But I don't do this approach since I preferred to do it manually and programmatically, so I don't have to record all the event's that I need to test)

I assign a `accessibilityIdentifier` to every views/buttons and etc, that I have so I can call/compare it inside the UITest Class.

I grouped them depending on the scene that I want to test like for example I created test cases that would start from login. And separate test cases that would start from registration, depending on the state of your app.

In addition to this, I have created a simplified pattern and created an Example project to implement UI Testing from this repository https://github.com/michaelhenry/AutoBot

Update:

For testing views that are created using SwiftUi,
 You can use the method “.accessibility(identifier: “your_control_accessibility_identifier”)”

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no general answer to your question, since UI testing depends essentially on the UI of your app.
In the app I am currently working on, I test scene by scene, i.e. the controls of every view controller. So, some of them are related to basic functions, some to iCloud setup, etc.. I believe - but I don’t have too much experience - that testing scene by scene is straightforward, if your scene structure is clear, and it is relatively easy not to omit essential functions.